# Can't connect from winXP in Virtual Box to ftp on my linux host

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, ftp

I've try to connect to my host system (which is Xubuntu) that run ftp server,

```
 ftp://10.0.2.2/
```

I use default ftp built in WindowsXP:

error (I only have Polish version):

> Wystąpił błąd podczas otwierania folderu na serwerze FTP. Upewnij się,
>   czy masz uprawnienie dostępu do tego folderu.
>
> Szczegóły: Ustanowienie połączenia z serwerem nie było możliwe

something like:

> There was error while opening a folder on FTP server. Make sure you
>   have access to that directory.
>
> Details: Connection to the server was not possible

but windows XP give error that he can't access the directory. When I connect to http server it work fine, and when I connect to localhost from linux it also work.

FTP is in standard configuration (it work on localhost and from other machines in local network) and I didn't do anything with iptables, OS is Xubuntu 13.10.

I can't find config for ftp, nmap show: `OpenBSD ftpd 6.4 (Linux port 0.17)`

My Virtual Box network settings is set to NAT (default option).

Comment: We can't help if you do not provide more information. What is the actual error you're getting in your ftp client? What is your host-virtual network layout, which ftp server is it or better yet—what is your "standard" configuration (different ftp servers have different "standards")?

Comment: It could be many problems, for instance: did you change which port the server receives info on? We just cannot tell with the information given.

Comment: @Woody I didn't touch ftp at all, just standard installation.

Comment: @Czar updated the question.

Comment: @jcubic I actually struggled through Polish version (my native language is Russian) and only then I spotted the translation :D

Answer (score 1):

If your FTP server is configured to work in Active mode you need to make sure that your XP firewall is configured to allow your FTP client to listen to connections from server AND as your XP is on the virtual machine you have to ensure that your virtual network is configured in the manner which will allow the ftp server to connect to it.

Alternatively you can configure your FTP to work in Passive mode.

Here is a [good explanation](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) of Active and Passive FTP modes. For information on how to configure your FTPD in Passive mode consult `man ftpd` and `man 5 ftpd.conf` or use google-fu :)

Comment: I've disabled firewall, got the same error. I can't access virtual machine from my host machine, I can only access linux host from Virtual XP. My net VirtualBox config is NAT.

Comment: See my updated answer then.

Comment: Feel free to tick the accept tick if my answer helped. :)